# What compound is formed in this case?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I read from a source that the aqueous solution of ferrous sulfate ($\ce{FeSO4}$) gives an unstable brown compound on treating with $\ce{NaNO2}$ and dilute $\ce{HCl}$. Well, it is quite understandable that it is the $\ce{HNO2}$ formed in situ that further causes the reaction. But what is the reaction and what is that unstable compound formed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Structure of FeSO₄ • NO?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10641/what-is-the-structure-of-feso%e2%82%84-no)

Comment: @Mithoron, it is not, cause I didn't know what it was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iron(II) reduces nitrite to nitrogen monoxide which forms a brown pentaaquanitrosyliron(II) complex with the iron(II) ions.

$$\ce{NO2^{-} + Fe^{2+} + 2H+ -> NO + Fe^{3+} + H2O}$$

$$\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^{2+} + NO -> [Fe(H2O)5NO]^{2+} + H2O}$$

Iron(II) can also reduce nitrate to nitrogen monoxide. This is used in the [brown ring test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrate_test) to determine the presence of nitrate in aqueous solutions.