# Brown ring from the anion detection of NO3-

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Today in our practicals I observed that when I did the wet test for nitrate (Making a 1 ml solution of salt solution+$\ce{FeSO4}$ solution+hot concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$);
The brown ring appeared for a very short time and then disappeared.

But later on I came to know that it was nitrate only. What may be the possible reason for this temporary appearance of a tinge of a brown colour and then its sudden disappearance?

Comment: Probably transient formation of $\ce{NO2}$.

Comment: [See this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76778/in-brown-ring-test-how-is-no-formed) and links therein.

Answer (score 4):

The brown ring formed in the confirmatory test for the nitrate ion is due to the complex called nitroso ferrous sulphate, or pentaaqua nitrosyl iron (II) sulfate with the formula $\ce{[Fe(H2O)5NO]SO4}$.
The concentrated sulfuric acid decomposes this complex and brown ring disappers in a few seconds when $\ce{H2SO4}$ moves to the upper layer. This is why slow addition of the acid (through the sides of the test tube) is advised.

Comment: So you mean that excess of concentrated H2SO4 makes brown ring disappear.

Comment: But if we add excess then it turns black...

Comment: I tried it out too